# I can't add a "font=" option to my tkinter button in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make a program but when I try to run it, it says it doesn't understand what the font varible option is. how do I fix this?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.ttk import *
import time

#this is not all of the code

class button:
    def __init__(self,texxt,command,gridx,gridy):
        self.texxt = texxt
        self.command = command
        self.gridx = gridx
        self.gridy = gridy

        Button(people, text=texxt,font=("Arial",20),command=command).grid(row=gridx, column=gridy)
```

I want it to just work without an error message.